# The $n$-dimensional Lebesgue Integral Properties

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

**Background Information:**

In the theorem here we fix a complete Lebesgue-Stiltjes measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}$ associated to the increasing  right continuous function $F$, and we denote by $M_{\mu}$ the domain of $\mu$. Thus, for any $E\in M_{\mu}$ $$\mu(E) = \inf\{\sum_{1}^{\infty}[F(b_j) - F(a_j)]:E\subset \bigcup_{1}^{\infty}(a_j,b_j]\} = \inf\{\sum_{1}^{\infty}\mu((a_j,b_j]):E\subset \bigcup_{1}^{\infty}(a_j,b_j]\}$$

Theorem 1.18 - If $E\in M_{\mu}$, then \begin{align*}
\mu(E) &= \inf\{\mu(U): E\subset U, U \ \text{open}\}\\
&= \sup\{\mu(K):K\subset E, K \ \text{compact}\}
\end{align*}

Theorem 1.19 - If $E\subset \mathbb{R}$, the following are equivalent

a.) $E\in M_{\mu}$

b.) $E = V\setminus N_1$ where $V$ is a $G_{\delta}$ set and $\mu(N_1) = 0$

c.) $E = H\cup N_2$ where $H$ is a $F_{\sigma}$ set and $\mu(N_2) = 0$

Lebesgue measure $m^n$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the completion of the $n$-fold product of Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$ with itself, that is, the completion of $m\times \ldots \times m$ on $B_{\mathbb{R}}\otimes \ldots \otimes B_{\mathbb{R}} = B_{\mathbb{R}^n}$, or equivalently the completion of $m\times \ldots \times m$ on $L\otimes \ldots \otimes L$.

The domain $L^n$ of $m^n$ is the class of Lebesgue measurable sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

In what follows, if $E = \prod_{1}^{n}E_j$ is a rectangle in $\mathbb{R}^n$, we shall refer to the sets $E_j\subset \mathbb{R}$ as the sides of $E$.

**Question:**

> Suppose $E\in L^n$
>
> a.) $m(E) = \inf\{m(U):E\subset U, U \ \text{open}\} = \sup\{m(K):K\subset E, K \ \text{compact}\}$.
>
> b.) $E = A_1\cup N_1 = A_2\setminus N_2$ where $A_1$ is a $F_{\sigma}$ set, $A_2$ is a $G_{\delta}$ set, and $m(N_1) = m(N_2) = 0$.
>
> c.) If $m(E) < \infty$, for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is a finite collection $\{R_j\}_{1}^{n}$ of disjoint rectangles whose sides are intervals such that $m(E \ \triangle \ \bigcup_{1}^{n}R_j) < \epsilon$.

Proof a.) - Let $E\in L^n$ and $\epsilon > 0$ then by definition of product measures there exists a countable family $\{T_j\}$ of rectangles such that $E\subset \bigcup_{1}^{\infty}T_j$ and $\sum_{1}^{\infty}m(T_j) \leq m(E) + \epsilon$. For each $j$, applying theorem 1.18 to the sides of $R_j$ we can find a rectangle $T_j\subset U_j$ whose sides are open sets such that $m(U_j) < m(T_j) + \epsilon 2^{-j}$. Let $U = \bigcup_{1}^{\infty}$, then $U$ is open and $$m(U) \leq \sum_{1}^{\infty}m(U_j) \leq m(E) + 2\epsilon$$
thus we can define $m(E) = \inf\{m(U):E\subset U, U \ \text{open}\}$.

I am not sure how to show the second part.

Proof b.) Not sure

Proof c.) Let $m(E) < \infty$ and $\epsilon >0$. So we know that $m(U_j) < \infty$ for all $j$. Now since the sides of $U_j$ are countable unions of open intrvals, take a sufficient number of subunions to obtain rectangles $V_j\subset U_j$ whose sides are finite unions of intervals such that $m(U_j) \leq m(V_j) + \epsilon 2^{-j}$. Take $N$ to be sufficiently large,then $$m(E\setminus \bigcup_{1}^{N}V_j) \leq m(\bigcup_{1}^{N}U_j\setminus V_j) + m(\bigcup_{N+1}^{\infty}U_j) < 2\epsilon$$ and $$m(\bigcup_{1}^{N}V_j\setminus E) \leq m(\bigcup_{1}^{\infty}U_j\setminus E) < \epsilon$$ thus we have $$m(E\triangle \bigcup_{1}^{N}U_j) < 3\epsilon$$

I am not sure if more details needed to be added to make this more clear. Any suggestions is grealy appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Suppose $E\in \mathcal{L}^n$
>
> a.) $m(E) = \inf\{m(U):E\subset U, U \ \text{open}\} = \sup\{m(K):K\subset E, K \ \text{compact}\}$.
>
> b.) $E = A_1\cup N_1 = A_2\setminus N_2$ where $A_1$ is a $F_{\sigma}$ set, $A_2$ is a $G_{\delta}$ set, and $m(N_1) = m(N_2) = 0$.
>
> c.) If $m(E) < \infty$, for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is a finite collection $\{R_j\}_{1}^{n}$ of disjoint rectangles whose sides are intervals such that $m(E \ \triangle \ \bigcup_{1}^{n}R_j) < \epsilon$.

**Proof a.)**

**Part 1**: Let $E\in L^n$ and $\epsilon > 0$ then by definition of product measures there exists a countable family $\{T_j\}$ of rectangles such that $E\subset \bigcup_{1}^{\infty}T_j$ and $\sum_{1}^{\infty}m(T_j) \leq m(E) + \epsilon$. For each $j$, applying theorem 1.18 to the sides of $T_j$ we can find a rectangle $U_j \supset T_j$ whose sides are open sets such that $m(U_j) < m(T_j) + \epsilon 2^{-j}$. Let $U = \bigcup_{1}^{\infty}U_j$, then $U$ is open and
$$m(E)\leq m(U) \leq \sum_{1}^{\infty}m(U_j) \leq \sum_{1}^{\infty}m(T_j) +\epsilon\leq m(E) + 2\epsilon \tag{1}$$
thus we have proved $m(E) = \inf\{m(U):E\subset U, U \ \text{open}\}$.

**Part 2**: Now, let us prove $\mu(E) =\sup\{\mu(K):K\subset E, K \ \text{compact}\}$.

First suppose $E$ is bounded. Then there is $k\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $E\subset [-k,k]^n$. Then, $[-k,k]\setminus E \in \mathcal{L}^n$ and then,  by part 1,
$$\mu([-k,k]^n\setminus E) = \inf\{\mu(U):([-k,k]^n\setminus E)\subset U, U \ \text{open}\}$$
So , for any $\varepsilon>0$, there is $U$ such that $([-k,k]^n\setminus E)\subset U$, $U$ is open and
$$\mu([-k,k]^n\setminus E)\leq \mu(U) \leq \mu([-k,k]^n\setminus E) + \epsilon$$
So we have,  for any $\varepsilon>0$, there is $U$ such that $([-k,k]^n\setminus U)\subset E$, $U$ is open and
$$\mu(E)=\mu([-k,k]^n)-\mu[-k,k]^n\setminus E)\geq \mu([-k,k]^n)-\mu(U) \geq \\ \geq \mu([-k,k]^n)-\mu([-k,k]^n\setminus E) -\varepsilon=\mu(E)-\varepsilon$$
Note that $([-k,k]^n\setminus U)$ is closed and bounded, so it is compact and $\mu([-k,k]^n\setminus U)=\mu([-k,k]^n)-\mu(U)$.
So we proved that for any $\varepsilon>0$, there is $K$ (take $K=[-k,k]^n\setminus U$) such that $K\subset E$, $K$ is compact and
$$\mu(E)\geq \mu(K) \geq \mu(E)-\varepsilon$$
So we have proved that, if $E\in \mathcal{L}^n$ is bounded then
$$\mu(E) =\sup\{\mu(K):K\subset E, K \ \text{compact}\}$$

If $E$ is not bounded, since for all $K\subset E$, $\mu(K)\leq \mu(E)$, we
$$\sup\{\mu(K):K\subset E, K \ \text{compact}\} \leq \mu(E)$$

Define, for $j\in \mathbb{N}$,$j>1$ $E_j=E\cap [-j,j]^n$. Note that $\{E_j\}_j$ is a monotone non-decreasing sequence of measurable sets and
$$E=\bigcup_jE_j$$
So, since $\mu$ is continuous from below, we have $\lim_{j\to \infty}\mu(E_j)=\mu(E)$.

Now, given any $\varepsilon>0$, since each $E_j$ is in $\mathcal{L}^n$ and is bounded, there is $K_j$ compact, such that $K_j\subset E_j$   and
$$\mu(E_j)-\frac{\varepsilon}{j}\leq \mu(K_j) \leq \mu(E_j)$$
So we have $\lim_{j\to \infty}\mu(K_j)=\mu(E)$.
So we have
$$\mu(E) =\sup\{\mu(K):K\subset E, K \ \text{compact}\}$$

So we have proved that, if $E\in \mathcal{L}^n$ (bounded or not) then
$$\mu(E) =\sup\{\mu(K):K\subset E, K \ \text{compact}\}$$

**Proof b.)**

It follows exactly as the proof of the Theorem 1.19. See my answer in

[Real Analysis, Folland Theorem 1.19 Borel Measures](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1825002/real-analysis-folland-theorem-1-19-borel-measures/1826394#1826394)

See in my answer there, the part **General Case**, item "a.) implies b.)" and item "a.) implies c.)".

**Proof c.)**

Let $m(E) < \infty$ and $\epsilon >0$. Let $\{U_j\}_j$ be the family of open rectangles as in item a.) part 1 above. From $(1)$, we have that  $m(U_j) < \infty$ for all $j$.

Now since the sides of $U_j$ are countable unions of open intervals, then for each $j$, take a suitable subunion to obtain a rectangle $V_j\subset U_j$ whose sides are finite unions of intervals such that $m(V_j) \leq m(U_j) \leq m(V_j) + \epsilon 2^{-j}$. So, we have,

$$m(E)\leq m(U) \leq \sum_{1}^{\infty}m(U_j) \leq \sum_{1}^{\infty}m(V_j) +\epsilon \leq \sum_{1}^{\infty}m(U_j) +\epsilon \leq m(E) + 2\epsilon $$

Take $N$ to be sufficiently large, then

$$m(E\setminus \bigcup_{1}^{N}V_j) \leq m(\bigcup_{1}^{N}U_j\setminus V_j) + m(\bigcup_{N+1}^{\infty}U_j) < 2\epsilon$$
and
$$m(\bigcup_{1}^{N}V_j\setminus E) \leq m(\bigcup_{1}^{\infty}U_j\setminus E) < \epsilon$$
thus we have $$m(E\triangle \bigcup_{1}^{N}V_j) < 3\epsilon$$

Since $\bigcup_{1}^{N}V_j$ can be expressed as a finite disjoint union of rectangles whose sides are intervals, we have proved c.).

Comment: For part a.) we have $$\mu([-k,k]^n\setminus E) = \inf\{\mu(U):([-k,k]^n\setminus E)\subset U, U \ \text{open}\}$$ So for any $\epsilon > 0 $ there is a $U$ such that $([-k,k]^n\setminus E)\subset U$, $U$ is open and this is what I don't seem to understand: $$\mu([-k,k]^n) - \mu([-k,k]^n\setminus E) \geq \mu([-k,k]^n) - \mu(U)$$ Is it because $-\mu([-k,k]^n\setminus E)$ will be the supremum? I understand the next step since $([-k,k]^n\setminus E)\subset U$.

Comment: Also, for the case where $E$ is not bounded you define $j\in\mathbb{N}$, $j > 1$, $E_j = E\cap [-j,j]^n$ how is $E_j$ bounded? i.e. How is $E_j$ bounded from below and bounded from above?

Comment: For b. from the link the general case states that $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite. I remember we discussed that was the case for section 1.5 does that apply as well for section 2.6?

Comment: I still don't understand the logic here, to me the last inequality works since we are subtracting i.e. we have $$\mu([-k,k]^n\setminus E) \leq \mu(U)$$ so then $$-m([-k,k]^n\setminus U) \geq -\mu(U)$$ is that correct?

Comment: @Wolfy , For part a.) : Since $$([-k,k]^n\setminus U)\subset E$$ then 
$$([-k,k]^n\setminus E)\subset U$$
So 
$$\mu([-k,k]^n\setminus E)\leq \mu(U)$$
So
$$\mu([-k,k]^n)-\mu[-k,k]^n\setminus E)\geq \mu([-k,k]^n)-\mu(U) $$

Comment: @Wolfy 
we have $$\mu([-k,k]^n\setminus E)\leq \mu(U)$$
So, multiplying both sides by $-1$, we get 
$$-\mu[-k,k]^n\setminus E)\geq -\mu(U) $$

Comment: I see, ok I understand that now thanks

Comment: @Wolfy , A set $E\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is bounded is there is $K\in \mathbb{R}$, $K>0$, such that 
$$E \subset \{x\in \mathbb{R}^n : \|x\|\leq K\}$$
It is easy to see that given any set $E\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, 
for $j\in \mathbb{N}$,$j>1$ 
$$E\cap [-j,j]^n\subset \{x\in \mathbb{R}^n : \|x\|\leq j\sqrt{n}\}$$
So $E\cap [-j,j]^n$ is bounded.

Comment: Ahh I see ok I just needed to see the definition again, I understand that now too thanks

Comment: @Wolfy 
For part b. Yes, the Lebesgue mesure is $\sigma$-finite also for 
$\mathbb{R}^n$. It is easy to prove:
$$\mathbb{R}^n =\bigcup_j^\infty[-j,j]^n$$

and, for all $j$, $\mu([-j,j]^n)=(2j)^n<\infty$.